# Django: How to navigate multi-level reverse relationships?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-related-manager

I have several models that are related hierarchically:

- Projects have one or more Experiments
- Experiments have one or more Scans
- Scans have one or more Scan Decisions

Simplified Models:

```py
class Project(models.Model):
  id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Experiment(models.Model):
  id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
  project = models.ForeignKey('Project', related_name='experiments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Scan(models.Model):
  id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid4, editable=False)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=127, blank=False)
  experiment = models.ForeignKey('Experiment', related_name='scans', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class ScanDecision(models.Model):
  id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=true, default=uuid4, editable=False)
  scan = models.ForeignKey('Scan', related_name='decisions', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

If I have a specific Scan Decision and I want to get the Project associated with that decision, how can I do so?

The [Django documentation speaks of *backward relationships*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/) but the examples seem limited to a single level of relationship.

For example, to get the `ScanDecision` associated with a `Scan` I could do something like:

```py
sd = ScanDecision.objects.get(id=1)
sd.scan_set.all() # Returns all scan objects related to the specific ScanDecision
```

But what if I want  to get the `Project` that is associated with the `ScanDecision` indirectly through `Scan` and `Experiment`?

e.g., something like this but without all the steps?

```py
sd = ScanDecision.objects.get(id=1) # The desired ScanDecision object
s = sd.scan_set.all() # Gets the related Scan object
e = s.experiment_set.all() # Gets the Experiment related to the selected Scan object
p = e.project_set.all() # Gets the Project related to the selected Experiment object
```

Ideally I'd like something like:

```py
sd = ScanDecision.objects.get(id=1)
p = sd.project_set.all()
```

Note: Each object only knows about it's immediately antecedent object, e.g. there is an ForeignKey relationship setup only between the child and parent objects, not any other levels. Thus `ScanDecision` has an FK to `Scan` but not to `Experiment` or `Project`. Similarly, `Scan` has an FK to `Experiment` but not to `Project`.

Comment: Can you add your models to the question, just with the relevant relationship fields? If `ScanDecision` has a foreign key to `Scan` then use that field on a `ScanDecision` instance to access the related `Scan`, same with all the other FKs, `sd.scan.experiment.project` for example

Comment: I've updated the the question to include simplified models. So, since there are FK's between the various models I can use `sd.scan.experiment.project` and it should return the correct project?

Comment: yes, exactly `sd.scan.experiment.project`

Comment: @DaveMackey yes, you are following multiple foreign key relationships forwards. You might want to look at [`select_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) to fetch all the related objects in a single query to improve performance, otherwise a query will execute every time you access a foreign key

Answer (score 1):

Based on your update you can use forward relationship `sd.scan.experiment.project`. To answer the question though to access backward relationship you could do `decisions = project.experiments.scans.decisions.all()`